# Zepellin Crowsale buyTokens error

Tags: truffle, tokens, crowdsale

I'm trying to use the buyTokens function of the Zepellin Crowsale interface, but this gives me an error, without any log to be able to debug

```
contract TokenA is MintableToken, PausableToken, DetailedERC20 {
    constructor(string _name, string _symbol, uint8 _decimals)
        DetailedERC20(_name, _symbol, _decimals)

}

contract TokenACrowdsale is Crowdsale, MintedCrowdsale {

  constructor(
    uint256 _rate, 
    address _wallet,
    ERC20 _token 
  )
    Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)

}
```

**truffle console**

> balances
>
> account[0]=8eth account1=4eth

```
let token=await TokenA.new('va','va',18)

token.balanceOf(accounts[0])  //0

await token.mint(accounts[0],web3.utils.toWei(10000000),token.address)
token.balanceOf(accounts[0]) //10000000 va

let crow=await TokenACrowdsale.new(web3.utils.toWei('500'),accounts[0],token.address)

await token.transfer(crow.address,web3.utils.toWei('200000','ether'))

token.balanceOf(crow.address) // 2000000 va

await crow.buyTokens(accounts[1],{from:accounts[1],value:web3.utils.toWei('1','ether')}) //Error
```

[ropsten transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x3c08742a6a8f93845ebaa94fed2dd8d414afc7c3d6c842933650c71ad067a7f8)

how do i fix this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using `MintedCrowdsale` which requires for the crowdsale to have mint permissions on the token contract.

```
await token.addMinter(crow.address)
```

If you do not want for the crowdsale to mint tokens you have to inherit from AllowanceCrowdsale.